# Bad PKCS7 padding. Invalid length 0. Python Encryption to C# Decryption

Tags: c#, python, cryptography, aes, pycrypto

I'm trying to share data between a Xamarin/.Net/C# prgram and a python program using AES CBC. I'm able to encrypt a message in .Net and and decrypt that message in python successfully, but not vice versa. That is, when I encrypt in python first and try to decrypt that message in C#, I get the exception: "Bad PKCS7 padding. Invalid length 0"

Here is my python encryption using in Python:

```
salt = 16 * b'\0'
keyIV = PBKDF2(Config.SECRET, salt).read(48)
key = keyIV[:32]
iv = keyIV[-16:]
aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)

# padding
length = 16 - (len(textToEncrypt) % 16)
print(len(textToEncrypt))
textToEncrypt += length * b'\0'
print(len(textToEncrypt))

encrypted = aes.encrypt(textToEncrypt)
encoded = base64.b64encode(encrypted)
return encoded
```

And here is the decryption in C#:

```
if (textToDecrypt == null || textToDecrypt.Length == 0)
            return "";

        textToDecrypt = textToDecrypt.Replace(" ", "+");
        byte[] bytesToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(textToDecrypt);
        string decryptedText;
        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            byte[] salt = new byte[16];
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes crypto = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Config.SECRET, salt);
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.Key = crypto.GetBytes(32);
            aes.IV = crypto.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cStream = new CryptoStream(mStream, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cStream.Write(bytesToDecrypt, 0, bytesToDecrypt.Length);
                }
                decryptedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(mStream.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return decryptedText;
```

The key and iv match between programs, but the encryption string in python comes out to be much shorter than encrypting the same string in C#. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> length = 16 - (len(textToEncrypt) % 16)
> textToEncrypt += length * b'\0'
> ```

That's not how PKCS7 padding works.

The thing about padding is that you need a way to identify it so that you can remove it later, without accidentally leaving some behind or taking off some data thinking that it was padding.

PKCS7 does this by padding with bytes whose value is the number of padding bytes. So the padding will be one of

```
01
02 02
03 03 03
04 04 04 04
...
16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16
```

Why have a padding of 16? Well if the length of your data is an exact multiple of the block size (16 bytes), and you opted not to add any padding at all, then when you came to remove the padding you might find that your data naturally ended in `01` or `02 02`, etc, and you'd remove those valid data bytes thinking that they were padding. So you need to add a full block of padding in this case.

The problem with your code is that it uses the value `00` for the padding.

---

> the encryption string in python comes out to be much shorter than encrypting the same string in C#. Thanks for any help.

I think you might be getting your encodings mixed up. `Encoding.Unicode` is UTF16-LE, which uses 2 bytes per character. It would be very unusual to use this from Python: it's more likely that you're using something like UTF-8, which uses 1 byte per character for common Western characters. It's hard to say for sure without knowing how you're turning your Python string into a byte string.

---

With AES, the IV needs to be <strike>random</strike> *unpredictable* (it can be public, but it mustn't be the same as a previous thing you encrypted). It's common to randomly generate it and then add it onto the beginning of your ciphertext. Don't derive it from your key.

Comment: For CBC The IV needs to be more than random, it should be [unpredictable](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3883/18298).

Comment: @kelalaka Are there any random (*not* pseudo-random) number sequences which are predictable? If an RNG produces predictable values, surely it's not sufficiently random? I don't have a crypotographic background, but intuitively the set of predictable numbers is a superset of the set of random numbers, not the other way around (i.e. you can get unpredictability without randomness, but not the other way around)?

Comment: Rfc2898DeriveBytes uses pseudo-random function. The point is  [Dual_EC_DRBG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_EC_DRBG).

Comment: @kelalaka I don't think that addresses my question? I didn't advocate using `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` for the IV

Comment: [CSPRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) that we prefer with a good seed. You did not advocate but also did not give one. True randomness is hard to achieve. [Hardware random number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator) are generally slow and may require special medium, and this is generally used as a seed for CSPRNGs. Are there any *true* random (not pseudo-random) number sequences which are predictable? I don't know. For example, probably you know better, python os.urandom

Comment: Good to read [What is the difference between TRNG and CSPRNG?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/63555/18298) and [When is an RNG a CSPRNG, a CSRNG, or a TRNG?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/48730/18298)

Comment: Going back to my point, you said "The IV needs to be **more** than random, it should be predictable". My question is, isn't randomness a stricter requirement than predictability? That is, is it not true that all random sequences are unpredictable, and that not all all unpredictable sequences are random?

Comment: The first paragraph [Randomness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness). Can you define your randomness?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207764/discussion-between-canton7-and-kelalaka).